# Rails, ActiveRecord, multiple where statements on nested attributes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, nested-attributes

I have an problem with my MySQL query in Rails/ActiveRecord.

First of all, my data model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_answers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answers, :through => :product_answers
end

class ProductAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :answer

  attr_accessible :answer_id, :product_id
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_answers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :product_answers
end
```

Now I have a problem with the search query:

For example, I have two products:

Product1: includes answer.id = 13 and answer.id = 25
Product2: includes answer.id = 14 and answer.id = 89

Now my first query looks like this:

```
Product.joins(:answers).where("answers.id" => [13,14])
=> [Product1, Product2]
```

I need to filter this query by all products with its answers including the combination of `answers.ids` in [13,4] and [25]

In a logical form, I need something like this:

```
where (answers.id = 13 and answers.id = 25) or (answers.id = 14 and answers.id = 25)
```

My first thought was something like this.

```
Product.joins(:answers)where("answers.id" => [13,14]).where("answers.id" => 25)
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there any good solution without making separated queries and then combining them?

Thanks

EDIT:

Ok I have a solution by combining several queries.

```
sub_answers = [[13,14], [25]]
  pre_product_list = nil
  sub_answers.each do |sub_answer|
    if pre_product_list.nil?
      pre_product_list = Product.joins(:product_answers).where('product_answers.answer_id' => answers).group("id").map{ |pa| pa.id }
    else
      pre_product_list = Product.joins(:product_answers).where('product_answers.product_id' => pre_product_list, 'product_answers.answer_id' => answers).group("id").map{ |pa| pa.id }
    end
  end
end
```

Does someone have maybe a better solution? I am looking forward for further advice.

Comment: Try this - `Product.joins(:answers).where("answers.id in (?) or answers.id in (?)", [13,14], [25])`

Comment: Hi,hi. Sry but this does`t work. For this statement i`m also getting product2, but i should only get product1 because product2 does`t include the answer.id = 25

Comment: Is this what you want!! - `Product.joins(:answers).where("answers.id in (?) or answers.id in (?)", [13,25], [14,25])`

Comment: Nope sry, has the same effect.